# Can you guide Solgaleo's nature using Synchronize lead?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I've been trying to get a Jolly Solgaleo leading with a synchronize jolly Abra, but it's been my 12th attempt and Solgaleo is anything but Jolly. Did they remove this mechanic in gen7?

Comment: RNGesus doesn't follow logic. You can find two shiny Pokemon in a couple of eggs or have several 50% chance fails. Just keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some threads, like [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74688680) or [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74628847), it seems that it is totally possible to synchronize the nature of Solgaleo.

The fact is that the Synchronize strategy only has a 50% chance of working. So it is totally possible that, even on your 12th try, you are being really unlucky. Try some more times, and you will end up getting your Jolly Solgaleo.

So no, this mechanic has not been removed in Generation 7.